# Use Continuous Integration to modify .NET project file

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, app-config, config-transformation

We have two code bases for testing and production. The only differences between these two code bases are in two files:

- The config file
- The build file (.csproj)

Maintaining two branches is a considerable effort which could be eliminated by merging the code bases into one and using a Continuous Integration (such as Hudson, e.g.) to modify the files according to the target environment.

As of VS2010, there is a very smart solution for the config files that allows us to define different config file transformations for two build configurations "Release-Test" and "Release-Prod".

However, we have some differences that are reflected in the project file (.csproj) such as:

- The name of the resulting assembly: Foo.exe vs. Foo-Test.exe.
- The assembly version.
- The ClickOnce deployment settings.

Is there any smart way how the csproj file can be transformed based on the build configuration, or how these settings can be extracted into a config file or C# code?

**Update:**

I tried with conditional MSBuild properties in the csproj file as suggested by @JaredPar, but it has a couple of caveats (see my comments for details). Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Shouldn't these changes be able to be controlled entirely through the project file?  I believe you can apply settings differently based on the selected build configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a single `csproj` and control elements like the assembly name based on a specific build configuration.  If so then you're looking for the `Conditional` element on MSBuild properties

```
<AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release-Prod'">Foo</AssemblyName>
<AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release-Test'">Foo-Test</AssemblyName>
```

Comment: You're so right! I used the condition before but was not familiar enough to think of it. I'll try this a.s.a.p.

Comment: It's been a long time... Having got back on this project I tried the approach thoroughly, also defining the clickonce settings with conditions. I have noticed that it works perfectly with the following workflow: start VS, open solution, select build configuration, hit "Publish". But if, after publishing, I change the build configuration and hit publish again, VS literally overwrites the settings of the newly selected configuration with the ones it cached from the publish before - thus modifying the csproj file. :-(

Comment: One more caveat: When I try to run (debug) the application, VS seems to take the assembly name from the first <AssemblyName> element it finds, disregarding the configuration. For any configuration with an assembly name different from the first one found, VS fails to run the application because it does not find the file under the name it expects.